# Is there any API in salesforce by which user read access on Opportunities records

Tags: apex, salesforcedx

Is there any api in salesforce by which by passing userid we can know read access on Opportunities.

Comment: Are you asking how to discover if some given user possesses CRUD access to the Opportunity object, or how to discover if some given user can see specific Opportunity records, or something else? Please [edit] your question.

Answer (score 0):

IF it is with respect to seeing any particular object records say Opportunity then you can look at Opportunityshare object.
Query for the user in the Opportunity share object, you get all the record's accessible to the user.

I dont think we have an API to check the sharing, may be good input for Salesforce ideas.

Thanks